# How to find quickly which subscribe() method has not onError?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

In code of my app is hundreds of subscribe() method call. Is a easy way to check which one has no onError handler?

I get 
`The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call` but I cannot find where it is?

Comment: post your entire logcat, also share if this is allowing your code to compile

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be with a lint rule, like [rxlint](https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint). From this [link](https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/RxLint-a-lint-rule-for-RxJava/):

> rxlint is currently a single lint rule that detects a subscription without a handler for onError().

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle (check [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.littlerobots.rxlint/rxlint)):

```
implementation 'nl.littlerobots.rxlint:rxlint:1.7.4'
```

Once added to your project an error will be shown like this:
[image]